# $AX=B$: How to solve for $X$ if elements of matrix A are matrices

Tags: pde, finite-difference, matrix, advection-diffusion

**Objective:** I am trying to solve for $C$ in 2D space (x,y) and time from following PDE. 
$$
\text{PDE: }\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \nabla\left(v.C - D\nabla{C} \right)=  \alpha.C
$$
**Method:** I discretized the above equation in 2D using finite-difference implicit scheme and as a result I get the following discretized equation.

$$p_1C^{n+1}_{i,j-1}+p_2C^{n+1}_{i-1,j}+p_3C^{n+1}_{i,j}+p_4C^{n+1}_{i+1,j}+p_5C^{n+1}_{i,j+1} = C^{n}_{i,j}$$
where, $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5$ are constant matrices in time. They are matrices instead of scalars because I am assuming $v$ and $D$ vary in space $(x,y)$ but constant in time i.e. $v(x,y)$ and $D(x,y)$. The variables  $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5$ are shown in the snapshot below:
[image]

I can solve for $C$ at each time by solving the system of equations as $A^{n+1}.C^{n+1}=C^{n}$.

**Issue:** Since $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5$ are matrices, I am not sure how to develop the matrix $A$. As an example for a system of $3\times3$ grid size, matrix $A$ will have the form as shown below. In that case how can I form matrix $A$ from $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5$, each of which is a matrix of size $3\times3$? I would really appreciate if someone can guide how to solve this. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Is $C$ scalar or vector?

Comment: Can you invert $C^{n+1}$? If yes, the isn't the answer $A^{n+1}=C^{n}.(C^{n+1})^{-1}$

Comment: $C^{n+1}$ is an unknown vector that I'm trying to compute. It contains value of each index at time $n+1$. $C^{n}$ at right hand side is a known vector.

Comment: @Pupil Sorry I meant to write can you invert $A^{n+1}$.

Comment: My issue is first how do I form $A$. If that is solved then probably, yes, I can invert that.

Comment: How can the $p_{i}$ variables be matrices? If they are matrices, then your second equation is a matrix on the left hand side but a scalar on the right hand side?

Comment: Please read under **Method** in my question why $p_*$ variables are matrices.

Comment: I did read it. I understand your motivation but the equation doesn't make sense. It's a matrix on the LHS but a scalar on the RHS. The dimensions don't match. Unless you are assuming an identity matrix on the RHS, but that imposes conditions on $p$.

Comment: The RHS in the equation is not a scalar. It's a one dimension matrix or vector in other words.

Comment: I'm talking about your 2nd equation. You have 5 terms on the LHS which are of the form "$p$ (which you say are matrices) times $C^{n+1}_{n,m}$ (which are scalars)" and the RHS is $C^{n}_{i,j}$. How can $C^{n}_{i,j}$ be a vector?

Comment: No, $C_{i,j}^n$ is a scalar because it is part of just one equation. I thought you were talking about the $AX=B$ which represents the system of equations.

Comment: Okay. So, if $C^{n}_{i,j}$ is a scalar then how do you explain your second equation? LHS matrix = RHS scalar? I've asked four times now and you won't answer which is probably why you haven't received a legitimate answer on this question yet. So, I'm dropping out of this question and will let someone else who understands what your asking to try and answer, good luck.

Comment: $C_{i,j}^n$ is a scalar, but $C^n$ is a vector of all the scalars coming from $C_{i,j}^n$.

Comment: As Bill Barth pointed out in his answer, the fundamental problem is that your discretization is not correct (or at least, not standard). For every $n$, you should treat $C^n$ as a *vector* of unknowns, so you end up with an equation of the form $AC^{n+1} = B C^{n}$, where $A,B$ are matrices (of finite differences, involving the coefficients $\nu$, $D$, $\alpha$). Deriving the right entries and getting them in the right place is a bit tedious but standard, and I would recommend looking at a standard textbook on finite difference methods (such as Morton/Myers or one of Uri Ascher's books).

Comment: @ChristianClason: In the formulation of $A^{n+1}.C^{n+1}=C^{n}$, $C^{n}$ is indeed a vector but of known quantities or in other words it's a known vector from initial condition. I have stated that many times in my other comments. I think I have figured out the answer to my question but I have not tested enough to say definitely that what I figured is right or not. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes, that's why $C^n$ is on the right-hand side (you solve for $C^{n+1}$). My point is that the missing step, which you are asking about, is sometimes called the *assembly* step (especially in finite element methods) and is discussed in the standard textbooks. (Your equation is a standard parabolic equation in divergence form, so you should find the full procedure there). If you do everything correctly, $p_1,...p_5$ should *not* be matrices but scalars (which do depend on $i,j$ via the coefficients).

Answer (score 4):

What is usually done when you have a matrix-like variable due to the dimensions of your problem and the indexing is to linearize the index. I.e., if you have $C_{i,j}$ you would replace that with $\hat{C}_k=C_{i,j}$ where $k=i\times N+j$ and $N$ is the number of points on one side of your $N\times N$ grid of points that you are doing finite differences on. This makes it easy to convert your kind of strange linear system into the standard form.

This means that you might end up representing $C$ as a single-indexed array in your program instead of treating it with double-indexing. There are other ways to accomplish this once you've written down the right linear system, but this method is compatible with most linear solver libraries which expect vectors of unknowns and right-hand sides.

Comment: Where are you suggesting to convert those indices? In the final $A.C^{n+1}=C^{n}$ equation they're already in that form.

Comment: @Pupil, no, that's your time index. You need to linearize over space, too.

Comment: @Pupil, or you need to express the forms of the $p_{*}$ matrices so that we can understand your problem better. Do they depend on $i$ and $j$?

Comment: @Pupil, just to be clear, you start with a scalar equation in $C(x,y,t)$, and then you appear to end up with a matrix equation for the discretized $C_{i,j}^n$ at each point. This can't be right. Either the $p_{*}$ matrices should have an $i$ and $j$ dependence, or you've done something wrong.

Comment: $p_*$ matrices have an $i$ and $j$ dependence as I mentioned in the question that they vary in space $(x,y)$. Each $p_*$ variable is a function of $v$ or $D$, and because $v$ and $D$ vary in space $(x,y)$ they are matrices of size $N_x\times N_y$. Hence, $p_*$ would be a matrix as well of size $N_x\times N_y$.

Comment: @Pupil, if they have an $i$ and $j$ dependence, too, then you can just linearize their indices, too. At that point, you should have $N=N_x \times N_y$ equations and $N$ unknowns which you can solve using lots of different techniques.

Comment: Bill Barth: I don't understand how would it solve the issue by linearizing the indices of $p_*$; agreed, that would make them vector but still how would I deal with those vectors in final $A$ matrix. Can you please explain it using an example in your answer?

Comment: @Pupil, it would be best if you gave the form of one of the $p_{*}$ at the very least. Right now what you have written an equation for the $i,j^{\rm th}$ location of $C$ but said that it's also got matrix coefficients. That just can't be right.

Comment: Bill Barth: I have included a snapshot which gives the expressions for $p_*$ in the question above. Thanks.

Comment: @Pupil, everything you wrote for the $p$s appears to be a scalar. What's your problem, again?

Comment: Bill, it appears to be a scalar in that snapshot because I have not assigned indices to it. However, $v$ and $D$ are matrices of the size of domain $(x,y)$

Comment: @Pupil, no, no, no, at each point $i,j$, they are scalars just like $C$. It's only a "matrix" when you let them run over the indices. But the indices coincide. Write it *all* down with a linearized index like I said, and you'll see it. You'll have an equation for $C_k$ with some $k+1$ and $k-1$ terms. That gives you the general form of a matrix row.